# Can't figure out this Postgresql recursive self-join

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab, recursive-query, self-join

Hey guys I have the following table:

```sql
+----+--------------+------------+----------+
| Id |     Name     |    Type    | ParentId |
+----+--------------+------------+----------+
|  1 | Team A       | team       | 2        |
|  2 | Initiative A | initiative | 3        |
|  3 | Initiative B | initiative | 4        |
|  4 | Initiative C | initiative | 5        |
|  5 | Product A    | product    | 6        |
|  6 | Product B    | product    | NULL     |
+----+--------------+------------+----------+
```

Essentially what I want to do is recursively self-join parents of the same type and only keep the highest level parent of the same type. 
To illustrate what I mean, if I were to perform the recursive join on the above table, I would expect the following result:

```sql
+---------+--------+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
| Team_Id |  Team  | Initiative_Id |  Initiative  | Product_Id |  Product  |
+---------+--------+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|       1 | Team A |             4 | Initiative C |          6 | Product B |
+---------+--------+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
```

I tried doing a recursive join through the `WITH RECURSIVE` CTE but I can't figure out how to "roll up" the parents of the same type in my final query.

Comment: Highest level of initiative is B?

Comment: Thanks @EdBangga, edited accordingly. Good catch.

Comment: *" tried doing a recursive join through the WITH RECURSIVE CTE but I can't figure out how to "roll up" the parents of the same type in my final query."* Maybe also posting the tryed recursive CTE as well

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you the required list of items - but you will have to transpose them in order to get a 1 row with multiple columns:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table AS t1
LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.parentId = t2.id
WHERE t1.parentId IS NULL OR t1.type <> t2.type
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to generate these columns in json and you can play around on converting json to your report.

But, you can use json_to_record() but requires pre-defined column types.

```
with cte as (
      SELECT
        '{' || translate( 
            (translate((json_agg
                (json_build_object(type || 'id', id, type || 'name', name)))::text, '[]', '')),
           '{}', '') || '}' as name          
      FROM table1 
      WHERE id in (
        select max(id) from table1 group by type)
)
select x.* FROM cte
cross join json_to_record(cte.name::json) AS x(teamid text, teamname text, initiativeid text, initiativename text, productid text, productname text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have solved it with the following Recursive CTE. I am able to see the top most parent of the same type with the results from this query.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE parent_rollup AS (
  SELECT
        -1,
        -1,
        NULL,
        NULL AS rolled_up_parent_group_uuid,
        NULL AS rolled_up_type
    FROM table t

  UNION

  SELECT
         t.Id,
         t.ParentId,
         t.type,
         t2.Id,
         t2.Type
    FROM table t
    LEFT JOIN table t1
      ON t.ParentId = t.Id
    JOIN parent_rollup t2
      ON t1.ParentId = t2.Id
)
```